# Activiti event for process instance creation?

Tags: events, listener, activiti, bpmn

I want to register an event listener, that must be called on creation fo new process instance in Activiti. Is there an Activiti event type for this?

Comment: do you mean the start event?: https://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/wf-process-def-listeners-execution.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I follow you, but perhaps you want to register an executionListener and associate it with the Start event of the process.

Execution listeners can be associated with the process instance, tasks, gateways and BPMN event symbols.

Cheers, Greg - BP3